# php curl with browser cookies

Tags: php, curl, cookies

i have a webservice like this 
http://www.sample.com/api/v2/exchanges/Web/stocks/Stock/lastN=200 
that return json
the main problem is you should login to http://sample.com to see this json otherwise you see 403 Forbidden error 
and this website use google authenticate for login, can i use browser cookie with curl for get this json?
this is the code i found but it didnt work for me

```
    function get_content($url,$ref)
{
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ch = curl_init();

$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $browser);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> this website use google authenticate for login

then login on gmail first, gmail will give you a special cookie which should allow you to fetch the json as authenticated.

> , can i use browser cookie with curl for get this json?

yup. you can get the cookie by logging in on your browser and check document.cookie in a js terminal, but sounds like a very inconvenient solution

> code i found but it didnt work for me

that code does not attempt to authenticate at all. for an example of google-authentication via gmail, check

https://gist.github.com/divinity76/544d7cadd3e88e057ea3504cb8b3bf7e